# Can O365 account alias addresses send as well as receive emails?

Tags: email, office365

We are looking to migrating over our email to O365 from IONOS POP/IMAP accounts where each user downloads onto their local Outlook PST file.

In our company everyone has 2 emails addresses, e.g `me@domain1.com` and `me@domain2.com`.

We are trying to plan this to avoid disruption so I have a question which neither MicroSoft nor IONOS have satisfactorily answered. I hope someone who have been through this process already can help.

If we set everyone up using the `x@domain1.com` email address, is there a way to allow the user to have a second mailbox for `x@domain2.com` under the same O365 account? MS support told me that users can set up aliases and receive emails into these other mail accounts, but for us we must be able to send/reply as that alias account as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have used simple Aliases to be able to receive email to Account A and have it show up in Account B. That works and that is what Microsoft told you.

Sending goes from the Default Account. Outlook has always worked this way.

If you wish to send from a different account (not Default), you would have to set up the Outlook Account to do this and the user would have to select the Account they are sending from.  This is not automatic.

So you can do what you want but there is a manual element to it.

Comment: Thank you. The requirement we have is to receive emails into `me@domain1.com`  and `me@domain2.com`. If I 'reply to' a `me@domain2.com` email it should have as its 'Reply-To' as `me@domain2.com`. Effectively operating as 2 separate email accounts. This can (I think) work if we purchased 2 licences for O365 for each employee, but looking to see if this can work under a single account. MS suggested aliases for receiving, and were less than convincing when asked about sending. It doesn't look to me like it can work without purchasing a separate account for each domain.

Comment: The second account must be a working account (my accounts are all working) so it may be you need to acquire another working account (purchase).

Comment: I'm still investigating this, and came across some articles suggesting MS released an update in June 2021 introducing a `sendFromAliasEnabled` setting that allows this to be setup. Have you come across that?

Comment: I think you mean this:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/617421/detailed-script-for-newbies-exchange-online-sendfr.html  ....   "Note that this script applies to an Exchange service with Microsoft for an own domain. Thus there are TWO related admin IDs that are involved. The Exchange Admin Center (EAC) can ONLY be accessed via a "Microsoft email""   ... If this applies to you, it might work. Still, somewhere in a email system, it has to look back and find the sender. I did not see that in your original post. That is part of using aliases.

Answer (score 1):

The best way (and automatable) to do this would be using shared mailboxes.

You can create as many as you want (not require a license and automatically shows up in Outlook) and allow user's Ownership/SendAs -> this way users would be able to send emails from as many email addresses as they want.

Educating them would solve it, but you could also set up forwarding on those shared mailboxes so users would get email to their Inbox.

Might seem complicated but it is a very good way to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thank you. This sound promising. So I understand, `user`@dom1.com` wuld create a shared mailbox `user`@dom2.com` and it being a shared mailbox would allow that user to send as `user2@dom2.com`. Is that right?

Comment: That is right.
create user@dom1.com and assign EXO license
create a shared mailbox user@dom2.com -> assign access for user@dom1.com
user can send as user@dom2.com as well as user@dom1.com

Answer (score 1):

I have found something different. According to this link, OWA should now support sendAs alias: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=59437